# How to make std::getline() include last empty line?

Tags: c++, std, getline

When using std::getline to read lines from a file, I need it to pick up each blank line at the end of the file.

```
    //add each line to lines
    while (std::getline(file, line))
        lines.push_back(line);
```

getline() is always skipping the last blank line of a file and not adding it to the lines vector. I need the final blank line to be included IF it's in the file. How do I do this?

Comment: It doesn't pick up the last blank line. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960596/getline-sets-failbit-and-skips-last-line

But I cannot find a workaround.

Comment: Note that `line\nline\n` has now final blank line, but this `line\nline\n\n` does have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is [by design](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

> Extracts characters from input and appends them to str until one of the following occurs (checked in the order listed).
>
> a) end-of-file condition on input, in which case, getline sets eofbit.
> ...
>
> If no characters were extracted for whatever reason (not even the discarded delimiter), getline sets failbit and returns.

That `failbit` will cause the stream’s `bool` conversion operator to return false, breaking the loop.

So, what I think you will have to do is make your loop check if `eofbit` is set on each successful read. If set, the last line was terminated by EOF and not by a line break, so there won’t be a subsequent line to read. If not set, there will be another line to read, whether it is blank or not.

```cpp
while (std::getline(file, line)) {
    lines.push_back(line);
    if (file.eof()) break;
}
if (file.eof() && file.fail()) {
    lines.push_back(“”);
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/4g3Vo9)